# HTML anchor tag isn't working and I don't know why

Tags: html, anchor

I'm having problems understanding why this isn't working. I have a single page with different sections. One section is 'Contact Us'; I want my menu to jump to that section. I also have a "Back to the Top" anchor.

The 'Back to the Top' is working perfectly.
The 'Contact Us' is not working.
I do not understand why one works but the other doesn't.

**Contact Us**
Link
`<a href="#Contact" style="text-decoration: none">Contact Info</a>`

Target
`<img id="#Contact" src="IDgif.gif" Title="Contact Us" style="width: 1px; height: 1px;">`

**Back to the top**
Link
`<a href="#top" style="text-decoration: none">Back to the top</a>`

Target
`<img id="#top" src="Header.png" title="Header" style="width: 531px; height: 110px;">`

I copied the working text and renamed the images and anchors and links.

Comment: The `id="#Contact"` must be changed to `id="Contact"` and `href="#Contact"` should be left as it is. Please do the same with the back to the top link, I can't seem to wrap my head around why that IS working. For more information regarding HTML ids please read: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. I also changed the 'Back to the Top' link.

Comment: Right! I'll put this as an answer, accept it so that it may help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The `id="#Contact"` must be changed to `id="Contact"` and `href="#Contact"` should be left as it is. Please do the same with the back-to-the-top link, For more information regarding HTML ids please read: https://w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp